# Relación uno a muchos con checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy creando un modulo donde un usuario tenga muchas empresas y una empresa tenga muchos usuarios, en el formulario de edición de usuarios estoy construyendo una lista con todas las empresas y cada una tendrá un checkbox

Las relaciones son de la siguiente manera:

Modelo Usuario:

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'IdUsuario'

  has_many :usuario_sucursales, foreign_key: "IdUsuario", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :empresas, through: :usuario_sucursales
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :usuario_sucursales, allow_destroy: true
```

Modelo Empresa:

```
class Empresa < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'IdEmpresa'
  has_many :usuario_sucursales, foreign_key: "IdEmpresa", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :usuarios, through: :usuario_sucursales
```

Modelo Usuario_sucursales:

```
class UsuarioSucursal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :usuario, foreign_key: "IdUsuario"
  belongs_to :empresa, foreign_key: "IdEmpresa"
```

formulario de editar usuario:

```
  <%= form_for(usuario, :method => :put, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal formulario-validado-update#{usuario.id}"}) do |f| %><!--ajax-->

      <div class="form-group">
        <% Empresa.all.each do |empresa| %>
           <label>
              <%= check_box_tag "usuario[IdEmpresa][]", empresa.id, f.object.empresas.include?(empresa) %>
              <%= empresa.Sucursal %>
           </label>
        <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

los strong_params de usuario:

```
def usuario_params
  params.require(:usuario).permit(:email, usuario_sucursales_attributes: [:id,  IdEmpresa: [] ])
end
```

El flujo de la consola luego de el submit del formulario

```
Started PUT "/usuarios/102" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-28 12:51:48 -0400
Processing by UsuariosController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "usuario"=>{"Nombre"=>"luis Carvajal", "empresa_id"=>"2", "email"=>"luis@yahoo.es", "IdEmpresa"=>["02"]}, "commit"=>"Actualizar", "id"=>"102"}
  Usuario Load (197.8ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [Usuarios].* FROM [Usuarios] WHERE [Usuarios].[IdUsuario] = @0  ORDER BY [Usuarios].[IdUsuario] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 102  [["IdUsuario", "102"]]
  Usuario Load (208.9ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [Usuarios].* FROM [Usuarios] WHERE [Usuarios].[IdUsuario] = @0  ORDER BY [Usuarios].[IdUsuario] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 102  [["IdUsuario", 102]]
  Perfil Load (377.6ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [perfiles].* FROM [perfiles] WHERE [perfiles].[IdUser] = @0 AND [perfiles].[Descripcion] = @1  ORDER BY [perfiles].[IdPerfiles] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int, @1 varchar(50)', @0 = 102, @1 = 'Catálogo de usuarios'  [["IdUser", 102], ["Descripcion", "Catálogo de usuarios"]]
Unpermitted parameter: IdEmpresa
  SQL (198.9ms)  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SQL (207.6ms)  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  Empresa Load (508.7ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [empresas].* FROM [empresas] WHERE [empresas].[empresamadre_id] = @0', N'@0 int', @0 = 2  [["empresamadre_id", 2]]
  Empresa Load (218.7ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [empresas].* FROM [empresas]'
  Empresa Exists (217.8ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  1 AS one FROM [empresas] INNER JOIN [usuario_sucursales] ON [empresas].[IdEmpresa] = [usuario_sucursales].[IdEmpresa] WHERE [usuario_sucursales].[IdUsuario] = @0 AND [empresas].[IdEmpresa] = @1  ORDER BY [empresas].[IdEmpresa] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int, @1 varchar(50)', @0 = 102, @1 = '02'  [["IdUsuario", 102], ["IdEmpresa", "02"]]
  Empresa Exists (228.6ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  1 AS one FROM [empresas] INNER JOIN [usuario_sucursales] ON [empresas].[IdEmpresa] = [usuario_sucursales].[IdEmpresa] WHERE [usuario_sucursales].[IdUsuario] = @0 AND [empresas].[IdEmpresa] = @1  ORDER BY [empresas].[IdEmpresa] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int, @1 varchar(50)', @0 = 102, @1 = '2'  [["IdUsuario", 102], ["IdEmpresa", "2"]]
  Rendered usuarios/_usuario.html.erb (1184.9ms)
  Rendered partials/_flash.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered usuarios/update.js.erb (1188.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2394ms (Views: 21.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2364.6ms)
```

me he estado guiando por [este](http://millarian.com/rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/) tutorial

el problema es que no se guardan los registros, en la consola me muestra `Unpermitted parameter: IdEmpresa` por lo que parece ser que el problema está en la definición de los parámetros fuertes. ¿Que puede faltar?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el _log_ de la petición que se muestra en la consola?

Comment: Gracias por comentar @Gerry ya modifiqué en mi post lo que muestra la consola

Comment: params.require(:usuario).permit(:email, usuario_sucursales_attributes: [:id,  IdEmpresa: [] ])
Esa definicion de idEmpresa: [] no se si sea correcta intenta solo permitir :idEmpresa

Comment: Segun la guia que estas siguiendo el parametro tiene que llamarse en plural "When this form is submitted, any checked Groups will be associated through Memberships to the User by way of the magic *_ids= method. "

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en que idEmpresa no esta bien definido como parámetro.

```
  params.require(:usuario).permit(:email, usuario_sucursales_attributes: [:id,  :IdEmpresa ])
```